# Generalized linear models and noncanonical link function

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

When using the canonical link function for GLMs, it is true that $g(\mu) = \theta = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta$.  Is this not the case when using a link that isn't canonical?  For example, say we're using a log link with gamma regression, how would $\theta$, $\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta$, and $\mu$ relate?  From my current understanding with GLMs, I do not see a problem with $g(\mu) = \theta = \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol\beta$ for any $g(\cdot)$, canonical or not.

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking because I don't understand what you're trying to express with the equation "$\theta=X\beta$". Since not everybody uses the same notation to describe GLMs, please try to explain what your symbols mean.

Comment: @whuber I am not sure what notation you use, but in all GLM literature that I have read, this is the notation used...

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't clear things up, because I have no idea what GLM literature you have read.  One thing I am confident of is that you have read only a very tiny part of it--nobody can read it all.  Either by explaining what your symbols mean, or by using clear English, please tell us what your question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes $g(\mu)=X\beta$ holds regardless of what $g$ is, because that is what you are postulating as the model. You call it the canonical link when $g$ is the mean-canonical parameter transformation of the exponential family (you are also postulating the family). There are nice properties associated with the canonical link, like that the family parametrized by $\beta$ is also an exponential family. By contrast, if you use something like the identity link $\mu=X\beta$, you will usually have a curved exponential family (exception is when you're in a gaussian family). The most common non-canonical link in my experience is the probit link. Instead of using the inverse of a logistic variable CDF as in usual logistic regression, you use the inverse of a normal CDF. That said, I seem to remember most of the asymptotic theory working out the same with reasonable non-canonical links (McCullagh & Nelder is the reference I learned glm's from).

Comment: Log-gamma is used a lot for severity of event modeling.